# TLS 1.3 early data where to put $ssl_early_data

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, tls1.3

I've set `ssl_early_data on;` to my nginx.conf (inside `http { }`) and according to these commands,

```sh
echo -e "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $host\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" > request.txt
openssl s_client -connect example.tld:443 -tls1_3 -sess_out session.pem -ign_eof < request.txt
openssl s_client -connect example.tld:443 -tls1_3 -sess_in session.pem -early_data request.txt
```

it does work properly.
According to the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_early_data) (https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_early_data), it is recommended to set `proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;`.
My question is: Where do I set this? Right after `ssl_early_data on;`, still inside `http { }`?

Comment: You should place it in the same block as your other `proxy_set_header` statements, otherwise it will be ignored.

Comment: Is there any way I can check it is working?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that settings the directive is enough is prevent the reply attacks. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098503/ssl-early-data-from-nginx-should-the-application-use-it-somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass Early-Data to your application. So you must have something like:

```
http {

   ...
   # Enabling 0-RTT
   ssl_early_data on;
   ...

   server {
      ...
      # Passing it to the upstream
      proxy_set_header Early-Data $ssl_early_data;
   }

}
```

Otherwise, you can render you application vulnerable to Replay Attacks: https://blog.trailofbits.com/2019/03/25/what-application-developers-need-to-know-about-tls-early-data-0rtt/